# Redis in-memory read replica of an RDS master

Tags: sql-server, redis, amazon-rds, read-replication

I have a high traffic web service.
Each request SELECTs some data from an MSSQL RDS.
The relevant tables in the RDS are very small, update/inserts will only happen few times a day.

In order to minimize each request time, I wanted to have some sort of an in-memory read replica Redis that will store those table in some sort of a key-value structure that I'll define in advance.
And to make sure that every time an Update/Insert is done on the RDS, it will update the Redis.
This application runs on multiple linux instances, so I'll need to have a way to deploy it to all of them, and obviously to keep them sync.

1.Does it make sense? maybe I should take a different approach?

2.If it does, can anyone share how would I achieve such thing? Is there an implemented tool in MSSQL/Redis or do I have to write some sort of a third-party app for it? couldn't find anything similar online.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: How do you sync data whenever an update/insert takes place to relevant table? Is that the issue you are finding a solution?

Comment: Yes, across multiple redis instances.

Comment: any possibility for you to use single centralized Redis instance for all application servers?

Comment: Nope... the app is heavily RDB.. just for this specific request which happens all the time I thought that storing the data in Redis could make it faster.

Comment: You will get some idea if you go through this https://www.slideshare.net/RedisLabs/redisconf18-techniques-for-synchronizing-inmemory-caches-with-redis